# .htaccess to block hotlinked image (blocking on my own site)

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I am attempting to block hotlinked images from a specific site and re-route to an externally loaded/hosted image somewhere else.

I made some edits to my .htaccess file

Buy it also seems to block my OWN site/domain from my own images.. (even though I believe I am allowing it?)

I cant seem to get things to work with JUST blocking the external site...(without blocking my own site from my own images?)

I've tried so many lines... I cant make heads or tails on what is the issue that is blocking images from my own site.

Here is is my latest attempt

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://myfakesite.net.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.myfakesite.net.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?external-site\.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://(www\.)?external-site\.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ https://path-to-externally-hosted-image.jpg [R,NC]
```

*I erroneously though this would be much easier.. LOL

How can I block external-site.com and allow everything from mysite.net?

Comment: I suggest you learn about rewrite logging to enable yourself to debug your http server. Take a look into the documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLog It allows you to understand the details of what is actually going on inside your rewriting module.

Comment: Added.. but no log file(s) created:

RewriteLog /home/xxx/xxxx/public_html/htaccess_rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5